# Open a popup on clicking the button in each row of the table

Tags: javascript, html, odoo-11

I have a table for Purchase orders. Each row has a Purchase order number and rate button. On clicking the rate button a popup will open in which the user can give rating and remarks to the vendor of that row. if rating is already given then the popup will show rating and remarks in read-only mode.

But my issue is rate button is working for only first row i.e., rating of only first-row purchase order is showing on clicking any row button.

**HTML Code**

```html
<table class="table table-hover o_my_status_table quotation_table">

    <thead>
        <tr class="active">
            <th> </th>
            <th>Purhase Order</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <t t-foreach="orders" t-as="order">
        <tr class="order_lines">
            <td><input type="submit" name="rate" id="rate" value="Rate" class="btn btn-primary" /> </td>
            <td><a t-attf-id="order_{{order.id}}" class="from-open-link" t-attf-href="#">
                <t t-esc="order.name" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </t>

</table>
```

**Modal Code**

```html
<div id="hidden_box" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-content" style="min-height:200px;max-width:400px;">
        <div class="modal-body" id="pop_html">
            <input type="hidden" t-att-value="order.name" t-esc="order.name" name="id" invisible="1" />
            <div align="center">

                <div class="rate">
                    <t t-if="order.company_rating == False">
                        <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rate" value="5" />
                        <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rate" value="4" />
                        <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rate" value="3" />
                        <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rate" value="2" />
                        <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rate" value="1" />
                        <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
                    </t>
                    <t t-else="">
                        <t t-if="order.company_rating=='5'">
                            <input type="radio" id="dstar5" name="rate" value="5" checked="checked" />
                        </t>
                        <t t-else="">
                            <input type="radio" id="dstar5" name="rate" value="5" />
                        </t>
                        <label for="star5" title="text">5 stars</label>
                        <t t-if="order.company_rating=='4'">
                            <input type="radio" id="dstar4" name="rate" value="4" checked="checked" />
                        </t>
                        <t t-else="">
                            <input type="radio" id="dstar4" name="rate" value="4" />
                        </t>
                        <label for="star4" title="text">4 stars</label>
                        <t t-if="order.company_rating=='3'">
                            <input type="radio" id="dstar3" name="rate" value="3" checked="checked" />
                        </t>
                        <t t-else="">
                            <input type="radio" id="dstar3" name="rate" value="3" />
                        </t>
                        <label for="star3" title="text">3 stars</label>
                        <t t-if="order.company_rating=='2'">
                            <input type="radio" id="dstar2" name="rate" value="2" checked="checked" />
                        </t>
                        <t t-else="">
                            <input type="radio" id="dstar2" name="rate" value="2" />
                        </t>
                        <label for="star2" title="text">2 stars</label>
                        <t t-if="order.company_rating=='1'">
                            <input type="radio" id="dstar1" name="rate" value="1" checked="checked" />
                        </t>
                        <t t-else="">
                            <input type="radio" id="dstar1" name="rate" value="1" />
                        </t>
                        <label for="star1" title="text">1 star</label>
                    </t>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <t t-if="order.company_remarks">
            <input type="text" name="remarks" t-att-value="order.company_remarks" id="remarks" />
        </t>
        <t t-else="">
            <input type="text" name="remarks" id="remarks" value="" class="form-control text-left" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:10px;" />
        </t>
        <t t-if="order.company_rating == False">
            <input type="submit" name="button_id" value="Rate" id="rate_submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </t>
    </div>

<style type="text/css">
    .rate {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .rate {
        float: left;
        height: 46px;
        padding: 0 10px;
    }

    .rate:not(:checked)>input {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
    }

    .rate:not(:checked)>label {
        float: right;
        width: 1em;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 30px;
        color: #ccc;
    }

    .rate:not(:checked)>label:before {
        content: '★ ';
    }

    .rate>input:checked~label {
        color: #ffc700;
    }

    .rate:not(:checked)>label:hover,
    .rate:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
        color: #deb217;
    }

    .rate>input:checked+label:hover,
    .rate>input:checked+label:hover~label,
    .rate>input:checked~label:hover,
    .rate>input:checked~label:hover~label,
    .rate>label:hover~input:checked~label {
        color: #c59b08;
    }
</style>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("remarks").defaultValue = "";
    $(".btn").on('click', function () {
        $('#hidden_box').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

I know the button would not work like this as written in js. Kindly help me with this.

Comment: Rating is showing if click on any button or first row button.

Comment: popup is opening but has values of first row only

Comment: can you show me your code how to put your value on that modal for hidden fields

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery selector $(".btn") only works for the first element with that class.

If you want to trigger your script for clicks on every row, you need to get all the relevant elements another way. I would suggest [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), using something like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
   var buttons = querySelectorAll("input.btn")
   buttons.forEach(element => {
     element.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // using vanilla JS
      var el = querySelector("#hidden_box")
      el.classList.toggle("show"); // you would need a CSS class of "show" to make the modal visible
      // or using your original jQuery
      $('#hidden_box').modal('show');
     })
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thankyou for your answer, but you gave me the answer according to the remarks actually I need to open a popup on clicking the button whose input type is submit and class is ".btn" as you can see in my question. Kindly let me know how can I do it through button

Comment: Oh whoops I totally misread your question. I've updated my answer.

Comment: popup is not opening, is there any other way?